# Distribute a Python without additional libraries and interpreter

Tags: python

I have a simple application. When I compile it in .NET I can just distribute the .dll or .exe without having an installer.

But how do I do this with Python? For example we have machine without the Python interpreter or with the Python interpreter but without 3rd party libraries.

Comment: could you tell me why this question is bad?

Comment: The way you framed the question is... painful. And the heart of the question is probably not quite up to StackOverflow standards.

Comment: Now it should look better. I am no native so my english can be painfull. I will try to improve quality of the post.

Comment: I think my edits are accurate, and will make your question clearer

Comment: thanks. It looks much better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a couple of options:

1. Provide an installer for Python. Once they've installed Python, they're good. They've already had the .NET runtime installed - this is really no different (except Microsoft didn't embed Python into their OS)
2. Use [Portable Python](http://portablepython.com/). You can actually build your own version (though I've never done it so I have no clue how hard it would be).
3. Use [cxFreeze](http://cx-freeze.sourceforge.net/) or [py2exe](http://www.py2exe.org/). This packages the python interpreter up along with your source so it *looks* like just one .exe but actually contains more
4. Use IronPython [this way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2518814/distributing-ironpython-applications) or distribute it in some other fashion.
5. If you don't require access to the local machine, use [Flask](http://flask-wtf.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) or some other Python framework/microframework and host the app on the web using something like Heroku's free tier.

There might be some other options as well, but those are probably the most common.

Answer (score 2):

Use [Py2Exe](http://www.py2exe.org). It makes a .exe file out of your script, including the interpreter and required libraries. It's going to be bigger than your script though because of the interpreter.

Comment: thx. I never compiled python. I am forced because i want to show my code. I dont portable computer so it is hard for me. Some people dont understand that i see.

Comment: "Enter link description here"?

Comment: @BryanOakley Strange, I swear I wrote Py2Exe there ;)